# How to get the embedding of any vocabulary token in GPT?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, language-model

I have a GPT model

```
model = BioGptForCausalLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt").to(device)
```

When I send my batch to it I can get the logits and the hidden states:

```
out = model(batch["input_ids"].to(device), output_hidden_states=True, return_dict=True)
print(out.keys())
>>> odict_keys(['logits', 'past_key_values', 'hidden_states'])
```

The logits have shape of

```
torch.Size([2, 1024, 42386]) # batch of size 2, sequence length = 1024, vocab size = 42386
```

Corresponding to `(batch, seq_length, vocab_length)`. If I understand correctly, for each token in the sequence, the logits is a vector of size `vocab_length` which points the model to which token from the vocabulary to use, after passing it to softmax. I believe that each of these tokens should have an embedding.

From my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76655508/how-to-get-the-vector-embedding-of-a-token-in-gpt) I found how to get the embeddings of each **sequence token** (shape `[2,1024,1024]` in my setting). But, how can I get the embeddings of each token in **the vocabulary** of the model? This should be of size `[2, 1024, 42386, 1024]` (BioGPT has a hidden size of length `1024`).

I'm mainly interested in just a few special tokens (e.g., indices 1,2,6,112 out of the 42386).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want an embedding representing a single token from the vocabulary. They are two answers that I know for that, depending on which embedding you want **exactly**.

#### 1st solution

The first layer in the model is a `torch.nn.Embedding`, which is under the hood a linear layer with no bias, so it has a `weight` parameter of shape `[V, D]` where `V` is the vocab size (42386 for you) and `D` is the dimension of the embedding (1024). You can access to the representation of a token `k` with : `model.biogpt.embed_tokens.weight[k]`. This is the 1024-sized vector that directly represents the k-th token.

#### 2nd solution

You can feed the model with a created sequence, containing just the token of which you want the representation. This representation corresponds to the input of the first attention layer of the model. For example, to get the 5th token representation:

```py
inp = torch.Tensor([[5]]).long()
output = model(inp, output_hidden_states=True)
print(output.hidden_states[0])
```

These two representations are not exactly the same, because the first one only represents a token, while the second represents the token in its sentence, which is a sequence of one single token. It is up to you to decide which one suits to what you want to do after.

Comment: This is great! Just to clarify, the difference between the 2 solutions is that the 2nd one combines the specific token (e.g., 5 -- `model.biogpt.embed_tokens.weight[5]`) with the positional embedding in the sentence?

Comment: Looking at the code, the second one seems to be the first one, multiplied by 32, plus the positional embedding. I didn't run it to check though

Comment: Any idea where the 32 is coming from? The only reference to that number from the paper is "32 accumulated steps"

Comment: The value comes from model.biogpt.embed_scale, which denotes how important is the text embedding compared to the positional embedding, but is does not seem to be related to what you mention from the paper